# How do I make an ajax calls internally in Laravel without using the route system

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes, alternate

In `Laravel`, I would like to know how to make `ajax` call internally without using the the `route` system. I'm not sure what other ways I can access internal methods, without routes.

The reason I'm looking for this is because the way the application is setup, routes always return html, even if a `JSON` response, because the framework is loaded inside the content area of a parent website (using different framework) which always had a header and footer(ugh, I know). I have another post about this, but lets please stick to the question.

I just need this framework to talk to itself, from the `$.ajax()` request, straight to the controller, bypassing the route, so maybe a `JSONP`, or some way to access methods directly without going overboard.

I know I did this sort of thing using FOSJsRouting from Symfony in a previous app to accomplish this sort of thing, but I had to make a wrapper to access the methods.  I don't want that kind of elaborate setup if possible here.

Are there other ways?

Comment: anything stop you from setting up different routes for ajax?

Comment: Ok, so maybe this info is relavant to this specific question, yes, theres a requirement that the `section/` is actually in the url, because the parent app will be loading in a subpath, so theres an .htaccess override, this FW only loads with that `section` in the url.  Otherwise its not even bootstrapped.  So, once its bootstrapped, the html exists.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046502/1369055](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046502/1369055)

Comment: modify your parent framework? after all, Laravel is just a PHP function in a `.php` file returns some string, so I don't think it can do much you if you already have extra string outside of the function call